# UIAlertView display delayed

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am using monotouch to develop an iPad application.  I noticed that the display of UIAlertView is always delayed. The delay sometimes can be a few seconds, depending on the code after UIAlert.Show(). It seems like the system is merely posting a message when executing UIAlertView.Show(), and moves on with the code after that line.  Is there anyway to display my UIAlertView right away?

Thanks,

Al

Comment: I've never noticed this.  Can you post a code sample?

Comment: are you calling `UIAlertView.Show()` on the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have other things running on the UI thread. Run your other code in another thread before you call your UIAlert.